# Spring SAML redirects to the wrong host after login

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

We have multiple nodes under haproxy load balancer and Nginx in each node redirecting requests to the application.

The users access our application through https://myapp.com

The application successfully redirects the user to the login page on the SSO server however once the user submits his credentials and the SSO server redirects back to the application, the saml/SSO page redirects the browser to localhost:port instead of the actual domain https://myapp.com

It seems that the Spring SAML lib ignores the domain that has provided in the configuration.

Comment: can u post your spring-xml? can u debug? can u put a breakpoint in SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler?

Comment: HTTP redirect caused by SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess() and happens because requestCache. requestCache is variable of type HttpSessionRequestCache that stores "cached" request in session attribute "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST".

This cache is used for redirecting to page requested by not-authenticated user after his authentication.

Comment: As Ohad said already, this is near impossible to asses without logs and configuration, please provide those and we might be able to help.

Comment: Did you get any answer?